# Equivalent of ftp commands prompt and hash in sftp

Tags: linux, unix, ftp, sftp

When I use `ftp` to connect to other server, after connecting we are using below commands.

1. prompt
2. hash

but now we have changed the process to `sftp`. If I gave the command `prompt` or `hash` after I connecting the server, it's saying

> invalid command.

Could you please suggest what are the alternate commands for `prompt` and `hash` in `sftp`.

Answer (score 1):

*(Assuming you are using OpenSSH `sftp` client)*

1. There's no equivalent to `prompt`. `prompt` command in `ftp` disables confirmation of transfers of individual files for wildcard commands like `mget` and `mput`. `sftp` never asks these confirmations. In other words, `sftp` behaves by default, like `ftp` with `prompt` does.
2. `hash` makes `ftp` display progress of files transfers using `#` (hash) characters. `sftp` does not have an equivalent. In interactive mode, `sftp` displays transfer percentage. In non-interactive mode it does not display a progress (only final statistics).